# what syntax is this? (tty_write_unlock)

Tags: c, function, syntax

When i read tty_io.c, i see this definition. What does this __releases() mean?

```
void tty_write_unlock(struct tty_struct *tty)
    __releases(&tty->atomic_write_lock)
{
    mutex_unlock(&tty->atomic_write_lock);
    wake_up_interruptible_poll(&tty->write_wait, POLLOUT);
}
```

Comment: A quick Google search turned up the answer: https://lists.linux-foundation.org/pipermail/linux-pm/2006-May/002354.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a preprocessor macro that ends up a generating some attribute attached to the function to give the compiler or another tool details about it.

Here's the definition in [compiler.h](https://github.com/mirrors/linux/blob/master/include/linux/compiler.h#L15) of the linux kernel (which is apparently what you are looking at):

```
# define __releases(x)  __attribute__((context(x,1,0)))
```

It's inside `ifdef __CHECKER__` which, according [to this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse), means that it's used by the static analyzer "Sparse".

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently](https://lists.linux-foundation.org/pipermail/linux-pm/2006-May/002354.html) `__releases` and `__acquires` are two macros defined in Linux's compiler.h header which are used with the [Sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse) static checker to count locks released and acquired (to make sure that they are balanced).

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor macros used by [Sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse)

> Sparse is a computer software tool designed to find possible coding faults in the Linux kernel

If you look at the wiki page you'll see that somewhere in an header file of linux, `__releases` is replaced by the `__attribute__` GCC extension.